# What is the genealogy of Judah ben Bava?

Tags: rabbis, family-members, historical-figures, mesorah-tradition

Is [Judah ben Bava](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8974-judah-b-baba), noted for continuing the tradition of ordination, the son of [Bava ben Buta](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/2276-baba-ben-buta), the Rabbi who was spared by Herod?

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Toldos Tanaaim V'Amoroim Volume 2 Page 137](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43957&st=&pgnum=137&hilite=) says that it is highly unlikely that Rabbi Yehuda ben Bava was the son of Bava ben Buta. Bava ben Buta lived in the times of Hordos (73/74 BCE - 4 BCE - [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_the_Great)) and was a student of Shamai Hazakain (50 BCE–30 CE - [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shammai)) while Rabbi Yehuda ben Bava was killed after Churban Beitar (135 CE - [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betar_%28fortress%29)).